# how to do search functionality

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Please help me out.
I'm making a search functionality. Below is My Code and User stories. I'm able to pass only the first User Story but not with the other stories. Can someone please help me out.

User Stories:

1. As an User if I search with Skills and location I should get the results which matched with the query.
2. As an User if I search with only Skills still I should get the results which matched with the query.
3. As an User if I search with only Location still I should get the results which matched with the query.
4. As an User if I search with invalid skills (J, A, B) or location I shouldn't get the results which does matched the query..

   ```
   var search = {
    get: function (req, res) {
       var locationQuery = req.params.locationQuery,
       skillsQuery = req.params.skillsQuery;

       Jobs.find({state: { "$regex": locationQuery, "$options": "i" }, Skills: { "$regex": skillsQuery, "$options": "i" }}, function(err, result) {
           if (err) {
               console.log('Not a Valid Search');
               res.status(500).send(err, 'Not a Valid Search');
           }else {
               res.json(result);
           }            
       });
    }
   };
   ```

Comment: even 4th story should be working..

Comment: User story 1 and 4 require both `state` and `skill` to match, while user story 2 and 3 matches either `state` or `skill`. If my understanding is right then you have two options here. Simple options is to write difference mongo queries and run appropriate query depending on the search query. Second option is to build dynamic mongo query depending on the search query. First option is simple but it requires multiple mongo queries, while the second option is tougher but allows you to manage everything in one single query.

Comment: User Story 4 must fail because it's an invalid input right. If a user enters a single character and start searching then it should not give results it must fail. As you said for User stories 2 and 3 second option can you explain briefly how to do?

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of optional support, It would be better to take search parameters as query in GET. You can take reference of the following code snippet.

```js
var search = {
 get: function (req, res) {
    var query = {};
    if(req.query.locationQuery){
      query.state = { "$regex": req.query.locationQuery, "$options": "i" };
    }
    if(req.query.skillsQuery){
      query.Skills = { "$regex": req.query.skillsQuery, "$options": "i" }
    }

    Jobs.find(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Not a Valid Search');
            res.status(500).send(err, 'Not a Valid Search');
        }else {
            res.json(result);
        }            
    });
 }
};
```

**Upadte:**

Define your route as:
`searchRoute.get('/', search.get);`

And you can send your query parameters as(through POSTMAN):

`localhost:3000/api/search/?skillsQuery="java,javascript"&lo‌​cationQuery="Mumbai`

Comment: Hey Tolsee, When I tried with this query for each query it is showing all the list of jobs.

Comment: can you share your get url?

Comment: If your find method is sending you all of the jobs than the query is not set properly. You may wanna check that. FYI, you should supply search parameters as query, like `/endpoint/search/?locationQuery=your-reg-ex`

Comment: In the postman i'm searching like this http://localhost:3000/api/search/java,javascript/Mumbai

Comment: here you must send search results in GET query parameter like, `localhost:3000/api/search/?skillsQuery="java,javascript"&locationQuery="Mumbai"

Comment: Tolsee I created a route like this searchRoute.get('/:skillsQuery/:locationQuery', search.get);

Comment: You can just create your route as `searchRoute.get('/', search.get);`. For your application it is not suitable to put your route as you have done.

Comment: If i put in this way how can i send queries ?

Comment: When you do like your way `localhost:3000/api/search/:skillsQuery/:locationQuery`, Think your user is not passing `skillQuery`. so the route will be `localhost:3000/api/search/Mumbai`. Now the route will not work.

Comment: So can you please help me which is the best way to make it work?